# Change limit importation of metadata via jspui?

Tags: dspace

I need import a file csv with 1000 rows via jspui interface. How i can change the limit importation of metadata via interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following setting allows you to change the limit.

https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-6_x/dspace/config/modules/bulkedit.cfg#L19

I know that it works in XMLUI.  I presume it will also work in JSPUI.